# HTML email and outlook

Tags: html, css, outlook

I wrote an HTML email template which seems to work well except of email client Outlook 2019 (version 16)

I have this CSS style

```
.badge {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0.25em 0.4em;
    font-size: 75%;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 1;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
    transition: color 0.15s ease-in-out, background-color 0.15s ease-in-out, border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
}

.badge-success {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #28a745;
}
```

And I use this it in this way

```
<span style="color: #ffffff;">WHITE</span>
```

It should show a Green badge ( background-color: #28a745; ) with white text  .
Outlook 16 only returns the text WHITE without the backgroud color , which makes it unreadable on a white background.

Does exists a solution ?

Can I specify a CSS style only for Outlook ? If yes how ?
For example what should I do if I would set CSS style to use

```
.badge-success {
    color: #000;
}
```

for Outlook email client

and

```
.badge-success {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #28a745;
}
```

for non Outlook email client ?

Full code of my HTML email is here:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <title>Blank Template for Bootstrap</title>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, "Noto Sans", sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji";
      font-size: 1rem;
      font-weight: 400;
      line-height: 1.5;
      color: #212529;
      text-align: left;
      background-color: #fff;
    }
    
    .badge {
      #display: inline-block;
      padding: 0.25em 0.4em;
      font-size: 75%;
      font-weight: 700;
      line-height: 1;
      text-align: center;
      white-space: nowrap;
      vertical-align: baseline;
      border-radius: 0.25rem;
      #transition: color 0.15s ease-in-out, background-color 0.15s ease-in-out, border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
    }
    
    .badge-success {
      color: #fff;
      background-color: #28a745;
    }
    
    .alert-link {
      font-weight: 700;
    }
    
    a {
      text-decoration: none;
      background-color: transparent;
    }
    
    .auto-style1 {
      font-size: 16px;
    }
    
    .auto-style2 {
      font-size: 16px;
      color: #003166;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <!--  color bar using tables -->
  <table style="width: 100%; " cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" class="border-width: 0;background-color: #CCFFFF;">
    <tr>
      <td style="background-color: #e3effb; border-bottom-width: 4px; border-bottom: 3px solid #b9d8f4; border-top: 12px solid #e3effb;"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <!-- grey cell background -->
  <table style="width: 100%; border-width: 0; " cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <td style="background-color: #FBFBFB;">
        <!-- container fluid emulator-->
        <table style="width: 100%; border-width: 0; " cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
          <tr>
            <td style="background-color: #FFFFFF;">
              <!-- alert css emulator blue -->
              <table style="width: 100%; border-width: 0; " cellpadding="2" cellspacing="4">
                <tr>
                  <td style="border-spacing: 0px; border-collapse: collapse; line-height: 24px; border-radius: 4px; margin: 0; padding: 12px 20px; border: 1px solid transparent;" align="left" bgcolor="#cce5ff" class="auto-style2">
                    <span lang="it">test</span></td>
                </tr>
              </table>
              <!-- alert css emulator yellow -->
              <table style="width: 100%; border-width: 0; " cellpadding="2" cellspacing="4">
                <tr>
                  <td style="border-spacing: 0px; border-collapse: collapse; line-height: 24px; font-size: 16px; border-radius: 4px; color: #856404; margin: 0; padding: 12px 20px; border: 1px solid transparent; background-color: #FFF3CD;
 border-color: #ffeeba;" align="left">
                    <span lang="it">test</span></td>
                </tr>
              </table>
              <!-- container for rows :: boostrap fluid emulator-->
              <table style="width: 100%; border-width: 0; " cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <!-- bootstraps rows emulator -->
                    <table style="width: 100%; border-width: 0; " cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                      <tr>
                        <td style="border-spacing: 0px; border-collapse: collapse; line-height: 20px; font-size: 16px; color: #2f3030; margin: 0; padding: 6px 10px; border-top: 1px solid transparent; border-bottom: 1px dotted #424040; border-left: 2px solid #514f4f; border-right: 2px solid #514f4f; background-color: #F8F8F8;"
                          align="left">
                          <table style="width: 100%">
                            <tr>
                              <td style="width: 80px; text-align: center;" valign="top"><span class="badge badge-success">
         <a href="pippo.com"><span style="color: #ffffff;">WHITE</span></a>
                                </span>
                              </td>
                              <td valign="top"><span lang="it">test</span></td>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td style="border-spacing: 0px; border-collapse: collapse; line-height: 20px; font-size: 16px; color: #2f3030; margin: 0; padding: 6px 10px; border-top: 1px solid transparent; border-bottom: 1px dotted #424040; border-left: 2px solid #bbb8b8; border-right: 2px solid #bbb8b8; background-color: #F8F8F8;"
                          align="left">
                          <table style="width: 100%">
                            <tr>
                              <td style="width: 80px; text-align: center;" valign="top"><span class="badge badge-success"><a href="pippo.com"><span style="color: #ffffff;">WHITE</span></a>
                                </span>
                              </td>
                              <td valign="top"> <span lang="it">test</span></td>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                        </td>
                      </tr>



                    </table>
                    <!-- end bootstrap rows emulator -->


                    <!-- end container for rows :: boostrap fluid emulator-->
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>

              <!-- alert css emulator yellow -->
              <table style="width: 100%; border-width: 0; " cellpadding="2" cellspacing="4">
                <tr>
                  <td style="border-spacing: 0px; border-collapse: collapse; line-height: 24px; border-radius: 4px; color: #856404; margin: 0; padding: 12px 20px; border: 1px solid #ffeeba; background-color: #FFF3CD;
 " align="left" class="auto-style1"><span lang="it">test</span></td>
                </tr>
              </table>


              <!-- end container fluid emulator -->
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>


        <!-- end grey cell background -->
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <table style="width: 100%; " cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" class="border-width: 0;background-color: #CCFFFF;">
    <tr>
      <td style="background-color: #e3effb; border-bottom-width: 4px; border-bottom:  12px solid #e3effb; border-top: 3px solid #b9d8f4;"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The CSS will have no effect on the HTML. The classes in the CSS aren't being used at all in the HTML.

Comment: Could you provide your HTML markup as well? And just throwing this out there while I'm at it, here's a useful website: [CanIemail.com](https://www.caniemail.com/)

Comment: It works perfectly in Thunderbird, Gmail , Horde, Roundcube , other .